# Is it possible to find a parent element and its child element using Selenium2Library Keywords?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have recently switched to Robot Framework from python + selenium. In python + selenium, we could:

```
parent = webdriver.find_element_by_css_seletor("parentCssSelector")
child = parent.find_element_by_css_selector("childCssSelector")
```

Personally, I really like this approach as it allows a "fine" way to locate an element. But after a few days of using Robot framework + selenium2library, I have not discovered a way to achieve this. May I ask if anyone knows how to do this using Robot framework + selenium2library?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Locating or specifying elements**

All keywords in Selenium2Library that need to find an element on the page take an argument, either a locator or now a webelement. locator is a string that describes how to locate an element using a syntax specifying different location strategies. webelement is a variable that holds a WebElement instance, which is a representation of the element.

**Using 'locator'**

By default, when a locator value is provided, it is matched against the key attributes of the particular element type. For example, id and name are key attributes to all elements, and locating elements is easy using just the id as a locator.

**For example:**
Click Element my_element

It is also possible to specify the approach Selenium2Library should take to find an element by specifying a lookup strategy with a locator prefix. Supported strategies are:

**Using CSS as locator**

css Click Element | css=div.my_class    Matches by CSS selector

**For more different locator examples please refer**

http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html